# Univention UCS - AD Takeover - At least one GPO is still missing in SYSVOL

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, domain, samba4

Using `Univention Corporate Server (UCS)` and trying to takeover an Active Directory on a `Windows Server 2008 R2`...

Following the guide:

https://docs.software-univention.de/manual-4.2.html#windows:adtakeover

Section: `9.4. Migrating an Active Directory domain to UCS using Univention AD Takeover`

I set on my new `UCS` server, the same values as on the `Windows Server 2008 R2` for the following parameters:

- DNS domain name
- NetBIOS domain name
- Kerberos realm
- LDAP base DN

I arrived to the point where I had to run the command:

```
> robocopy /mir /sec /z \\DLDC\sysvol \\ucsdc\sysvol
```

on the `Windows Server 2008 R2` as Administrator.

The above command completed successfully with the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Sep 15 09:22:19 2017

   Source : \\DLDC\sysvol\
     Dest : \\ucsdc\sysvol\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MIR /Z /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       1    \\DLDC\sysvol\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\DfsrPrivate\
      New File                98    ConflictAndDeletedManifest.xml
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\DfsrPrivate\ConflictAndDeleted\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\DfsrPrivate\Deleted\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\DfsrPrivate\Installing\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\
      New File                27    GPT.INI
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\Adm\
      New File             50768    wuau.adm
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\
      New File              5034    Registry.pol
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Applications\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Microsoft\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\
      New File              1098    GptTmpl.inf
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Scripts\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Scripts\Shutdown\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Scripts\Startup\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\USER\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\USER\Applications\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\USER\Documents & Settings\
      New Dir          2    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\USER\Scripts\
      New File                 6    psscripts.ini
  0%  
100%  
      New File               212    scripts.ini
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\USER\Scripts\Logoff\
      New Dir          2    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\USER\Scripts\Logon\
      New File                62    default-drives-map.bat
  0%  
100%  
      New File               144    home-directory-map.vbs
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\
      New File                23    GPT.INI
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\
      New File                 8    Registry.pol
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\Applications\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\Microsoft\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\
      New File              3552    GptTmpl.inf
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\Scripts\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\Scripts\Shutdown\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\MACHINE\Scripts\Startup\
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\USER\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{A99FB5BE-989E-407D-81C2-8E0563980EDE}\
      New File                84    GPT.INI
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{A99FB5BE-989E-407D-81C2-8E0563980EDE}\Machine\
      New File              8734    Registry.pol
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{A99FB5BE-989E-407D-81C2-8E0563980EDE}\User\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{CAD2E82F-9501-4507-8676-ACCF1DEB9820}\
      New File               116    GPT.INI
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{CAD2E82F-9501-4507-8676-ACCF1DEB9820}\Machine\
      New File              9466    Registry.pol
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{CAD2E82F-9501-4507-8676-ACCF1DEB9820}\User\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{FC6F93DA-46C2-4DE4-8FF3-F3994E796F9F}\
      New File                81    GPT.INI
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{FC6F93DA-46C2-4DE4-8FF3-F3994E796F9F}\Machine\
      New File              7737    Registry.pol
  0%  
100%  
      New Dir          0    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\Policies\{FC6F93DA-46C2-4DE4-8FF3-F3994E796F9F}\User\
      New Dir          1    \\DLDC\sysvol\MYDOMAIN.intranet\scripts\
      New File              6148    .DS_Store
  0%  
 99%  

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :        43        42         1         0         0         0
   Files :        20        19         1         0         0         0
   Bytes :    97.2 k    91.2 k     6.0 k         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:02   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:01


   Speed :              125198 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :               7.163 MegaBytes/min.

   Ended : Fri Sep 15 09:22:21 2017
```

Then I clicked the button Next but I got the following error:

```
"Could not fulfill the request. Server error message: At least one GPO is still missing in SYSVOL."
```

As you can see below:

[image]

On the Univention log: `/var/log/univention/ad-takeover.log` I got the following:

```
2017-09-14 21:19:24,268 GPO missing in SYSVOL: {31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}
2017-09-14 21:19:24,268 At least one GPO is still missing in SYSVOL.
```

Then, by recommendation of the following url:

http:// www.tecmint.com/samba4-ad-dc-sysvol-replication/

I tried the following commands:

```
# samba-tool ntacl sysvolcheck # first check
# samba-tool ntacl sysvolreset # the reset
# samba-tool ntacl sysvolcheck # second check
```

Where the first check got errors, but the second check had no errors.

These were the errors:

```
root@ucsdc:~# samba-tool ntacl sysvolcheck
ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): uncaught exception - ProvisioningError: DB ACL on sysvol directory /var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydomain.intranet O:LAG:SYD:AI(A;OICIID;0x001200a9;;;AU)(A;OICIID;0x001200a9;;;SO)(A;OICIID;0x001e01bf;;;BA)(A;OICIID;0x001f01ff;;;SY)(A;ID;0x001e01bf;;;LA)(A;OICIIOID;0x001e01bf;;;CO) does not match expected value O:LAG:BAD:P(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;SO)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;AU) from provision
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 176, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/ntacl.py", line 270, in run
    lp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1737, in checksysvolacl
    raise ProvisioningError('%s ACL on sysvol directory %s %s does not match expected value %s from provision' % (acl_type(direct_db_access), dir_path, fsacl_sddl, SYSVOL_ACL))
```

Before the reset I had:

```
root@ucsdc:/var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydomain.intranet/Policies# ls -la
total 56
drwxrwx---+ 7 Administrator System        4096 Sep 14 20:54 .
drwxrwx---+ 5 Administrator System        4096 Sep 14 21:00 ..
drwxrwx---+ 5 Administrator System        4096 Sep 14 20:54 {31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator System        4096 Sep 14 20:54 {6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator Domain Admins 4096 Sep 14 20:54 {A99FB5BE-989E-407D-81C2-8E0563980EDE}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator Domain Admins 4096 Sep 14 20:54 {CAD2E82F-9501-4507-8676-ACCF1DEB9820}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator Domain Admins 4096 Sep 14 20:54 {FC6F93DA-46C2-4DE4-8FF3-F3994E796F9F}
```

After reset:

```
root@ucsdc:~# ls -la /var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydomain.intranet/Policies/
total 56
drwxrwx---+ 7 Administrator Administrators 4096 Sep 14 21:18 .
drwxrwx---+ 5 Administrator Administrators 4096 Sep 14 21:18 ..
drwxrwx---+ 5 Administrator Domain Admins  4096 Sep 14 21:18 {31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator Domain Admins  4096 Sep 14 21:18 {6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator Domain Admins  4096 Sep 14 21:18 {A99FB5BE-989E-407D-81C2-8E0563980EDE}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator Domain Admins  4096 Sep 14 21:18 {CAD2E82F-9501-4507-8676-ACCF1DEB9820}
drwxrwx---+ 4 Administrator Domain Admins  4096 Sep 14 21:18 {FC6F93DA-46C2-4DE4-8FF3-F3994E796F9F}
```

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: this topic is discussed here: https://help.univention.com/t/univention-ucs-ad-takeover-at-least-one-gpo-is-still-missing-in-sysvol/6838

Comment: In Case anyone ever has the same issue: Linux Paths are case sensitve , Windows Paths are not. Check that all characters in the the GPO folders are Uppercase.